# How to parse a long output from Linux shell which is "not text-processing friendly"?

Tags: php, linux, shell, text-processing

I'm very new in programming. I'm writing a PHP application that need to execute a lot of Linux shell commands, parse the shell output, and then display those info on a webpage.

The problem I'm facing:
The output of some Linux shell commands are very long and not "text-processing friendly". They are arranged in a way that is easy for human to read but difficult to parse in PHP. For example, I having big problem to parse the output of `ifconfig -a` command correctly in PHP.

Can anyone give me some advices what is the best way to parse a long Linux shell output? For example, if there are many interfaces in my PC, the output of `ifconfig -a` could become very long, with different section/paragraph showing the details for different interface.

Assuming that the number of interfaces is variable, and the number of output lines in each paragraph is also variable, how should i write a PHP function that can adapt to changes and extract important information from each of the interfaces (e.g. IP address, netmask, broadcast, etc)?

Comment: Most of those types of apps simply read data from various places in /proc. You could read those directly instead. ifconfig will get data from /proc/net, for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of these programs is unstable. There was a DailyWTF episode about this some time back. Code which relies on it may break when the application is updated, when the environment sets up differently, or if the code is taken cross-platform.

Mark B is right, if a *machine* is supposed to read this information, go to /proc or wherever the data actually is. *Ad fontes!*

If you really want to hack it, `preg_match` on the lines to look for the interesting patterns.

Answer (score 2):

`explode()`ing on newlines (`\n`) gives you an array with one item per line, and when you loop through the array, and use `preg_split()` function accordingly.